# Need a ruby daemon

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

I'm trying to follow [Skinny Daemon](http://labs.headlondon.com/2010/07/skinny-daemons/) tutorial from [Head Labs](http://labs.headlondon.com/) since it does exactly what I need. I also like how the app is make as a gem, but it contains a thin server so I can get my app's pulse if I need it.

I've followed the tutorial and fiddled with it until the point where the gem can be built and installed. But when I try to start my gem it using the following command I get this:

```
$ myservice start
-bash: myservice: command not found
```

I suspect the tutorial is a little old and for some reason the gem installer doesn't add the gem location to my path.

How can I make this tutorial work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, using Jeweler is a little bit obsolete. Use `bundle gem` instead. Also I don't see in tutorial to specify in `.gemfile` that there is executable file in `bin`. How to do this you have here http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable. But if you use Bundler to create your gem scaffold then it will be automatically set to:

```
gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split($\)
gem.executables   = gem.files.grep(%r{^bin/}).map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
```

Comment: I followed the instructions but still after building and installing the gem I don't seem to be able to just call `myservice start`. myservice appears to be an unknown command.

Comment: Check that you have executable path in your `PATH` and that `myservice` file is there also. To get all RubyGems paths just run `gem env`.

Comment: ok, when I run the `gem env` command it tells me that `- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin`. But looking into that directory I can't see `myservice` gem.

Comment: So have you added `gem.executables` variable and rebuilded your gem and then installed it?

Comment: I've left it to default which was `gem.executables   = gem.files.grep(%r{^bin/}).map{ |f| File.basename(f) }`

Comment: I tried `gem.executables << 'myservice'` and it not installs the executable file at the right place which means I can now do `myservice start`. Thanks a lot